# House of representatives elections data from 1996-2012

Tags: data.gov

Is there an open access source for U.S. House of Representatives congressional district election results in data sets (preferably Excel) for the elections 1996-2012.   I have tried Dave Leip's site uselectionsatlas.org but the cost of getting the data sets needed will cost thousands of dollars.

Comment: for some reason i thought this would already be out there...figured it would be on openelections. house.gov definitely has this in pdf.

Comment: Wikipedia or wikidata doesn't have this either?